# Adobe Illustrator Auto Check 'Use Artboards'

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, artboard

I want to automatically check 'Use Artboards' check box, when exporting JPEG/PNG from Illustrator. Is there any way to do it? May I have to change some script file to avoid manual checking for every new export dialog box. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Illustrator used to save your export settings for each opened session (meaning you would only have to hit this checkbox once). Times have changed, and now export settings are not retained, leading to problems like yours.

There are two solutions:

1. Use the "Save for Web" option, which does retain settings like "Clip to Artboard" (the same thing as Use Artboards in Export).
2. Use an action, just like in Photoshop, where your Export has the settings saved. You could simply create an action called "Export with Artboard" that does only that action for you.

Best of luck!

Reference: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1041853

Comment: Does "Save For Web" have resolution setting?

Comment: @atilkan not explicitly no, Save For Web defaults to 72 DPI by default in both Illustrator and Photoshop. However, you can change the Image Size, which can be used to increase the size of the image, and in effect, the overall DPI if the image were shrunk to fit a smaller area.